# Controlling number of Threads for ManagedExecutorServices / Java EE 7

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

In Java SE one can use constructs like

```
ExecutorService es1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ExecutorService es2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

to control the number of threads available to the executor service. In Java EE 7 it's possible to inject executor services:

```
@Resource 
private ManagedExecutorService mes;
```

But how can I control the number of threads available to the managed executor service ? For example, in the application I'm writing, there is an executor service that has to be executed in a single thread. So I can't just let the platform choose its preferred number of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this setting should be set in the server settings, through admin console (in GlassFish for example), or during the creation of the service:

```
asadmin create-managed-executor-service --corepoolsize=10 --maximumpoolsize=20 concurrent/mes
```

- See [Create ManagedExecutorService, ManagedScheduledExecutorService, ManagedThreadFactory, ContextService in GlassFish 4](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/create_managedexecutorservice_managedscheduledexecutorservice_managedthreadfactory_contextservice).

Comment: Well, seems to be a poor concept that reminds somewhat to the old days of J2EE. But thanks for your disillutioning answer. (I'll upvote it, as far as I have the required 15 reps).